# Android: Authorizing myself to 3rd party web-site

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager, auth-token

I am developing a client-server app, which needs to access some database on the server (say, something like http://www.someserver.com/).

How can I authorize user on the server from Android phone using existing Google account on the phone?

I was thinking about AccountManager and AccountManager.getAuthToken(), but I can't find a way how I can use them for specified task.

Comment: It seems, the answer will be the same as for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276210/how-to-make-accountmanager-authtoken-and-openid-work-together-without-appengi]) question.